# Solve the equation with respect to x given a and b constants

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the equation with respect to x given a and b constants.

$$e^{bx}+ax=1$$

Comment: You order us to solve it. But what is your work on this subject ? 1) If you don't show that you have worked, your question will quickly be closed 2) Besides, there is no closed form expression of the solution.

Comment: I looked at solving the equation by Lambert W.   x = 1_w (e) .But if there are constants then the same solution will remain

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Lambert-$W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), you should get $$x=\frac1a - \frac1b\,W\big(\tfrac ba\,e^{b/a}\big).$$

Comment: Note that $x=0$ is always a solution.

Comment: exp(bx)+ax=1  ;    (1/a)exp(bx) +x=1/a ;  (b/a)exp(bx)+bx=b/a  ;  (b/a)exp(bx)=(b/a)-bx  ;   (b/a)exp(b/a)=(b/a  -bx)exp(b/a  -bx);                         b/a-bx=W((b/a)exp(b/a));                                                x= 1/a -1/b.W((b/a)exp(b/a))